# Color blending/compositing in web mapping frameworks?

Tags: raster, web-mapping, color

The color/layer blending capabilities of QGIS 2 produce marvelous results. Blended rasters are especially nice to look at. Blending is, to me at least, a better way of combining layers than mucking about with the transparency. I'm wondering how to achieve the same result in a web mapping framework.

Mapbox/TileMill supports a [wide range](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/comp-op/) of compositing operations but these don't work with base maps. I'm looking for a mechanism that does this in the browser. OpenLayers 3 seems capable of performing such operations but I can only find examples of how to dynamically control [brightness/contrast](http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/brightness-contrast.html). Maybe the rest is in the making?

I have a single-color raster that I want to blend/composite with the base map. I realize that blending changes the color but that's not a problem as I'm interest in perserving and communicating the saturation.

PS One of the options is to blend the layer and base map in QGIS, save as image, georeference image and upload to server as raster. This, of course, is a very undesireable way of proceeding.